# jquery - replace next element and add css class to next element

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I would like to replace next element of a given element and add css class to the next element. 
I tried like this but it didn't work.

```
$(".validate_txt_sContactFirstName")
    .next()
    .replaceWith('<div>2</div>')
    .addClass("atleastTwoChars");


<div class="xqh_Field">
    <nobr>
        <input name="ctl00$objContentPageTag$spzContactInformation$txt_sContactFirstName$txt"
        type="text" size="25"
        id="ctl00_objContentPageTag_spzContactInformation_txt_sContactFirstName_txt"
        class="xqh_TextBox_Edit validate_txt_sContactFirstName error"
        style="width:150px;margin-right:1px;">
        <div class="atleastTwoChars"></div>
    </nobr>
</div>
```

Comment: your question is not very clear.. you want to replace a element with '2*' ???

Comment: actually, it is replaceWith(<div>2*</div>), seems stackoverflow removed div tags.

Comment: please include your html code to provide better help

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".validate_txt_sContactFirstName")
    .next()
    .text(2);
```

This is what you could use here. That way only the content of the `<div>` is edited. If you need HTML replace `text(2)` with `html('<strong>2</strong>')`

Answer (score 0):

if i am getting you correctly you can do it in a very simple way, because when you already have the class `atleastTwoChars` in the div what is meaning of replacing it adding text in it and then add same class. you can just replace inner value of div.

```
$('.atleastTwoChars').html(2);
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qXydv/